# Backbone.js Collection Method Binding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am currently using Backbone.js collection and View and I am attempting to bind a collections function to a function inside of the view. I thought that I could simply create a function inside of the collection and then bind it inside of the view. Unfortunately, it keeps referencing the collections method. Here is my code.

```
var RightPaneCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'add', 'remove', 'remove_by_name');   // bind the methods to this scope
        this.el.html("");   // clear out the view
        this.collection.bind('removeByName', this.remove_by_name);
                    this.collection.bind('remove', this.remove);
    },
    remove_by_name: function(){ console.log("Removing by name inside view.")
    }
}

var RightPaneCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: RightPaneButtonModel,
url: "",
removeByName: function(){
    console.log("Removing by name inside collection");
}
});
```

I'd like to be able to do the falling

```
 rightPaneCollection.removeByName("foo");
```

and have it reference the view. I'm not sure I'm going about this in the correct manner. Currently the remove works correctly by referencing the remove method inside of the view.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Basically, I am triggering a "removeByName" event from the collection when the item is removed and I pass the name of the item that was removed.  In the View, I am binding to that event name and calling the view's function and accessing the name of the item being removed.

```
var RightPaneCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'remove_by_name');
        this.el.html("");   // clear out the view
        this.collection.bind('removeByName', this.remove_by_name);
    },
    remove_by_name: function(name){ 
        console.log("Removing by name inside view: " + name)
    }
}

var RightPaneCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: RightPaneButtonModel,
   url: "",
   removeByName: function(name){
       var itemToRemove = this.find(function(item){return item.get("name") === name;});
       if(itemToRemove) {
           this.remove(itemToRemove);
           this.trigger("removeByName", name);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Not quite, I'm trying to bind a function inside of the collection to a function inside of the view. For instance, you can do this.collection.bind('remove', this.remove); and then when instanceOfCollection gets called it references the remove method inside of the view as opposed to the collection.

Comment: @PhillipWhisenhunt I think you are confused.  When you call `collection.bind("remove", this.remove)` you are not binding to the `remove` function of the collection, but the "remove" event that the `remove` function triggers.  Notice how the [_remove implementation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-74) works.  It calls `trigger("remove", ...)`.  So, in my example, I implement `removeByName` and then trigger the "removeByName" event which I then bind to in the view. Does that make sense?

Comment: O, that makes a lot more sense. Yeah, I thought it was binding to the remove function. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but don't you have to manually trigger the event?

```
var RightPaneCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RightPaneButtonModel,
    url: "",
    removeByName: function(){
        console.log("Removing by name inside collection");
        this.trigger('removeByName');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That is what I have in my example... triggering the event after the item has been removed.  You can then bind to that event from anywhere.  You don't bind to functions in Backbone, but you do bind to events... so you need to trigger them if you want them to be fired.